# Re-Enabling HTTP services on my modem

Tags: http

On my modem configuration page provided by my ISP (address 192.168.1.1), I disabled the HTTP services. Now I'm not able to connect to the config page since HTTP has been disabled. How do I re enable it? Thanks.

Comment: try resetting it by pressing the reset button or tell the model of the modem.

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch : Hi, I guess that would work, but i found another solution to the problem, which I have posted below as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since HTTP services was disabled, I used telnet to login to my router config page. This is achieved by typing the command `telnet 192.168.1.1` on the terminal. There, different modem manufaturers provide various commands to configure the modem. Mine (UTStarcom) provides a command called `restoredefault` which sets the modem back to it's default settings. Issuing this command defaults the modem to it's factory settings (Http enbaled).However, you will be required to change back the factory password to the one provided by your ISP.